# Table doesn't display content in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wanted to create a LinearLayout for my Android App with text and tables in it.
The TextView is displayed but the TableLayout is hidden or something like that.

I can't figure out, what the problem is.

Here's some code of my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ListWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/listBackground" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutScreenMainText"
        android:text="@string/helpPage.mainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/helpPage.addNoteText" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/mainTextColor">
             </View>
        </TableRow>   
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean it is hidden?
TableLayout has nothing to display on it's own. Is it it's borders you want to see?

Comment: I like to display the TextView and the TableLayout with it's contents in one Activity. The problem is that only the TextView is shown and the TableLayout is not visible.

Comment: Ok, I found the mistake.
The outer LinearLayout's orientation was "horizontal". Can't work with this property ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's solution was so easy ;)
The Layout's orientation was "horizontal" and not "vertical".